# Как написать регулярное выражение для замены с учетом арифметических операций?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка, как заменить на $n число с $n * 2 (с умножением, например). Если в тупую написать, то просто заменяется текстом.

На примере VSCODE

[image: VSCODE]

Comment: Что за язык?...

Comment: В итоге получается 'id' => 143.03 * 2

Comment: А мне нужно чтобы он уже готовое решение подставлял:
 'id' => 286.06

Comment: Что за язык?...

Comment: Это нельзя сделать регулярным выражением. Шаг 1. Замена имен на числа. Шаг 2. Смотрите в сторону eval.

Comment: Боюсь это возможно только в языке perl с его расширенным синтаксисом регулярок и специальными флагами, которые по сути включают автоматический eval в строке замены

Answer (score 0):

Регулярные выражения "не умеют" выполнять арифметические операции с тем результатом который возвращают. Да и любые операции над результатом, в общем.

Обработка результата (например, само действие замены подстрок) - это задача той внешней среды, которая вызывает PCRE и получает результат совпадения.

---

Пример с JavaScript в роли вызывающей среды:

```js
let input = 'Строка с числом 8.2'; 
const result = input.replace(/[\d.]+/, match => match * 2); 
console.log(result);
```

Очевидно, что метод `replace` с переменными и лямбда-выражением, не являются частью регулярного выражения - это элементы самого языка программирования: работу по вычислению (умножению результата) и замене подстроки, выполняет его интерпретатор.